# Stack Overflow app iOS widget refreshing bug

Tags: bug, ios-app

After initially swiping to the left to open widgets the hot questions widgets shows questions presumably held in a local cache. They are displayed just long enough to read the questions before the widget refreshes with new questions. This especially happens if you haven't looked at the widget for a while, then swipe over. Then it's impossible to "go back" to the previous list of 3 questions. This is a daily frustration.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus Silver 128
- OS Version: Version 11.2 (Build 15C5111a)

Possible solution: allow the widget to use pages of hot questions so we can view them all.